# Clustering of facebook-users with k-means

Tags: node.js, facebook, cluster-analysis, k-means

i got a facebook-list of user-ids from following page:

[Stanford Facebook-Data](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/egonets-Facebook.html)

If you look at the facebook_combined data, you can see that it is a list of user-connections (edges). So for instance user 0 has something to do with user 1,2,3 and so on.

Now my work is to find clusters in the dataset.

In the first step i used node.js to read the file and save the data in an array like this:

```
array=[[0,1],[0,2], ...]
```

In the second step i used a k-means plugin for node.js to cluster the data:

[Cluster-Plugin](https://github.com/harthur/clusterfck)

But i dont know if the result is right, because now i get clusters of edges and not clusters of users.

UPDATE:

I am trying out a markov implementation for node js. The Markov Plugin however needs an adjacency matrix to build clusters. I implemented an algorithm with java to save the matrix in a file.

Maybe you got any other suggestion how i could get clusters out of edges.

Comment: Do you really have to use k-means here? Alternatively look up "graph-cut algorithms", or "finding cliques" (not clusters).

Comment: No, it has not to be k-means. I am trying it with markov. But maybe there is a better way to cluster data?

Answer (score 1):

K-means assumes your input data issue an R^d vector space.

In fact, it *requires* the data to be this way, because it *computes means* as cluster centers, hence the name k-means.

So if you want to use k-means, then you need

1. One row per datapoint (not an edge list)
2. A fixed dimensionality data space where the mean is a useful center (usually, you should have continuous attributes, on binary data the mean does not make too much sense) and where least-squares is a meaningful optimization criterion (again, on binary data, least-squares does not have a strong theoretical support)

On your Faceboook data, you could try some embedding, but I'd have doubts about the trustworthiness.

Comment: Okay. Now i heard about the markov-clustering and there is a library for NodeJS. I implemented a method to get the adjacence matrix of the data and fed the markov-clustering with it. But it took really much time. Maybe i should use other technology? Can you suggest anything?